# Why the developers use negative margin when they float items?

Tags: css, wordpress, margin

Why to use negative margin if i float items?

```
ul {
{negative margin}
}

ul li {
float:left;
margin-right:10px;
}
```

I saw that somewhere but I don't remember. Can you explain it why they use negative margin properties? I see same strange thing in the wordpress's twentyeleven theme.

Comment: Google is your friend: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/27/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/

Answer (score 0):

Negative values in margin got the same goal as positive. It's just presentation.

As @better_use_mkstemp links to you, negative values are allowed by W3C; then you can't consider it as "strange".

cf: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/27/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/